# How to handle user after registration?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I need to register my user's with both phone authentication and email authentication. I have successfully done both. However, with the way I've structured my code, it's a bit flimsy.

After a user registers with their phone number, they are automatically signed in. But before they gain access to the application I need them to register with their email as well but I can't do so until they are signed in with their phone.

```
Group {
        
        if (self.session.session != nil) {
            
            if user?.metadata.creationDate != user?.metadata.lastSignInDate {
                
                AppView()
                
            } else {
                
                EmailRegisterView()
                
            }

        } else {
        
            OnBoardingView()
        
        }
        
        
    }.onAppear(perform: {
        
        session.listen()
        
    })
```

With the code I have, if the user for some reason logs out of their account on the same day that they've created it, they will be taken to the EmailRegisterView() again which will cause problems.

Is there another way to redirect users to the EmailRegisterView() only if they are new users, and once they have finished there, send them to the AppView()?

Here is my code for the phone authentication...

```
func phoneRegister () {
    
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: self.verificationCode, verificationCode: self.code)
                              
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
                                  
        if error != nil{
                                      
            self.alertMessage = (error?.localizedDescription)!
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        }
        
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                                  
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You start with an open curly bracket and end with a closed parenthesis?

Comment: @ElTomato can you please elaborate

Comment: Oops.  My mistake...  My apology...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can add a key to user default and check the value every time the user open the app.
If the userdefault bool key, let's say IsUserRegistered, doesn't exist or is set to false, then you navigate to login page/register page and set the key to true. Otherwise, if the the key is set to true, you just display the home view.